# Clustering based on max distance between ALL points in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm working on a layer of thousands of points, some of points are very close together.

I want to group them into clusters according to the following rule:
"*The distance between all points within each cluster must not exceed 500m*".

I can do it  with symbology (distance : map units (500m)).

But how to assign a cluster to each point within the attribute table?

Comment: @JGH Yes it does

Comment: @JGH I changed my post. The max distance must be 500 m beteween ALL points.

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is not done in the attribute table. You rather define a cluster as rendering style in the layer symbolization of your points layer. Select cluster styling, where you have a field to define the distance (I used milimeters, but of course you can set ma units), see screenshot:

[image]

The size of the cluster-symbol (as well as almost everything else in the symbol: color, border-size, size of the text-font that indicates the number of clustered points and so on) can be modified according to how many points are clustered. In the screenshot above select the cluster symbol and style it accordingly. As you can see on the next screenshot, I used a simple marker to generate yellow circles - their size depends on the variable `@clustersize`, thus the more clustered points they represent, the bigger they are.

On the size field, select the data-driven override symbol (ε) and select assistant. In the opening dialogue (see next screenshot), add `@clustersize` as source and than define the values from/to (no. of clustered points, in my case: 0 to 50) and size from/to (size of the circles, 0 to 20 in my case) accordingly. My settings define that at 50 clustered points, the size reaches it's maximum value - which I set to 20. So symbols which contain more than 50 points will not be bigger than this maximum value of 20. You might also try different scaling modes.

It's trial and error to find adjustments that fit your needs. Maybe you also have to re-adjust your distance setting. And of course the zoom-level can change the optimal settings - optimal meaning here that you use the maximum range of sizes to distinguish between different number of points contained in a cluster but with minimal overlapping.

[image]

Comment: thank you for helping. I did what your are displaying but want to do it on attribute table not in symbology.